# Structured Streaming application crashes

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

So, I have a structured streaming application that is reading in 3 csv files from S3 on a 5 minute trigger interval.  A basic groupby is performed on the dataframe and then using the foreach output I asynchronously write out the records to an external data store.  After about 4-5 intervals, the spark job crashes and this is what I find in the logs:  Does anyone have a solution for this?  If not, what would your first steps to debug this be?

```
17/06/19 17:46:36 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at StreamFromS3.scala:65
17/06/19 17:47:31 WARN ClosureCleaner: Expected a closure; got com.ignitionone.es.ForEachOuput
17/06/19 17:48:19 WARN FileStreamSource: Listed 348653 file(s) in 47382.367306 ms
17/06/19 17:50:51 WARN FileStreamSource: Listed 348653 file(s) in 51272.664258 ms
17/06/19 17:55:50 WARN FileStreamSource: Listed 348707 file(s) in 50868.757278 ms
17/06/19 18:00:51 WARN FileStreamSource: Listed 348747 file(s) in 51256.287437 ms
17/06/19 18:00:51 ERROR ApplicationMaster: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
17/06/19 18:00:51 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Exception from Reporter thread.
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.ApplicationAttemptNotFoundException: Application attempt appattempt_1497453419814_0060_000001 doesn't exist in ApplicationMasterService cache.
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ApplicationMasterService.allocate(ApplicationMasterService.java:439)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.service.ApplicationMasterProtocolPBServiceImpl.allocate(ApplicationMasterProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ApplicationMasterProtocol$ApplicationMasterProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ApplicationMasterProtocol.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2045)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.instantiateException(RPCUtil.java:53)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.unwrapAndThrowException(RPCUtil.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl.allocate(ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor67.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.allocate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.AMRMClientImpl.allocate(AMRMClientImpl.java:277)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnAllocator.allocateResources(YarnAllocator.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$1.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:458)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.ApplicationAttemptNotFoundException): Application attempt appattempt_1497453419814_0060_000001 doesn't exist in ApplicationMasterService cache.
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ApplicationMasterService.allocate(ApplicationMasterService.java:439)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.service.ApplicationMasterProtocolPBServiceImpl.allocate(ApplicationMasterProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ApplicationMasterProtocol$ApplicationMasterProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ApplicationMasterProtocol.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2045)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.allocate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl.allocate(ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl.java:77)
... 9 more
```

Comment: `RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM` usually means your application was killed by YARN. My hunch is your application uses too much memory. The log shows there were 348747 files in the source. The data in the state store may be too large. You can try to increase `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` and see if this will still fail.

Comment: @zsxwing The number of files caught my attention too as it might put too much pressure on JVM. Why would `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` help here?

Comment: Increasing the partition number usually will decrease the size of each partition, then the data in StateStore may be able to fit into memory.

Comment: @zsxwing Why would the number of files in the source location effect the process though?  I thought it wouldn't matter since we set maxFilesPerTrigger to 3 so that it only consumes 3 files at a time.

Comment: You are using aggregation. It needs to remember all data to generate the answer. This is not a per batch answer. It generates answer based on the whole data.

Comment: It generates the answer based on the whole data if you've chosen outputMode: Complete.  However, I'm using outputMode: Update which it does not continue to hold and update the dataset within memory. It processes the interval and moves on.

Also, this error is occurring after 2 or 3 intervals of processing.  It's nowhere near close enough to maxing out memory on this cluster so it wouldn't make sense that it is crashing due to running out of memory for the main dataset.

Comment: However, you're definitely right about it being related to the file count.  I can run tests all day with smaller file counts and the application never crashes.  In fact, I wonder if it's only an issue with that file count and S3 as the source.  A solution would be to just run a lambda function to move the files into a processing directory and point spark to that.  Set a 1 day retention on the files in that folder and they will be deleted after 24 hours.  I'm more so just curious as to why that file count in s3 crashes the application at this point.